# Show distance from a polilyne in MapBox

Tags: javascript, api, maps, coordinates, mapbox

I was developing this polilynes code, and I need to display the polilyne distance completely, how do I do this?

Here below is the code I am using:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eQg-hnOFuRWOPWUhg8Lqq38Lc6Pi9uJc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: your link does not seem to work ;)

Comment: Some funny guy deleted it ;/ I already put it again

Comment: This is why the [ask] guide asks you to provide a [mre] and "Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included in the question itself". If the code disappears in the future, this question and answer will be of very limited value to future readers, as they cannot see the problem that this answer solves. Even though you have got an answer, please consider adding the code in question directly in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculates geojson with libs like [Turf.js](https://turfjs.org/).

For example, `turf/length` measures length of lineString, like below.

```
const line = turf.lineString([
  [-53.08074, -25.766767],
  [-53.097358, -25.77123],
  [-53.117901, -25.798796],
  [-53.147227, -25.801503],
  [-53.187904, -25.812659],
  [-53.235429, -25.811208],
  [-53.276227, -25.802679],
  [-53.305865, -25.788242]
]);

const len = turf.length(line, { units: "kilometers" }); // 24.96224597809012
```